# .htaccess throws 500 internal error with rewrite condition for non existing directory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make a facebook like user profile page using .htaccess
ie. http://example.com/<userid > will actually call http://example.com/sites/<userid >/<sub_page >
using thefollowing code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [NC,L]

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

It works perfectly well when the folder sites/<userid> exists but when it doesn't it throws 500 internal error. I've scoured the internet but couldn't go beyond this. Can someone please help with this.
Can i have a text file with all existing folders and somehow use that to generate a list in the .htaccess?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: What 500 error? Look in your web server's error log to see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules are looping. The regular expression `^([^/]+)/?(.*)$` is matching the rewritten URI `sites/something/something` and it's looping indefinitely (so your URI starts looking like: `sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/something/something` etc).

Either tweak your regular expression so that it doesn't liberally match what's after the first `([^/]+)/?` expression or add an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
```

Comment: if i want to add a forward slash to the original url :http://example.com/<userid > so it becomes http://example.com/<userid >/ how do i do that?